# When is a spring @configuration class executed?

Tags: java, spring

So when exactly is a @configuration class executed and what is the scope of it?

Is it one per session? One per entire application? But my next question is where does the bean return to after executing? Maybe this code will help you understand better what I mean.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {
   @Autowired
   Environment env;

   @Bean
   public DBConnection testBean() {
     DBConnection testBean = new DBConnection();
       testBean.setName(env.getProperty("testbean.name"));
       return testBean;
   }
}
```

So more or less when would this DBConnection be valid/initiated?

Comment: I suggest you read about Bean Lifecycle in spring. Spring reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html or this: http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/spring-framework-tutorial/java-spring-bean-lifecycle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotated class is just that, a class annotated with the `@Configuration` annotation. It does nothing on its own.

You need something to evaluate and process the class. This is done through bootstrapping. You have three options

1. Register the class with an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` instance.
2. Specify the class as a `<bean>` in XML configuration with the corresponding XML-enabled `ApplicationContext`.
3. Place the class in a package that is component-scanned.

These options are detailed in the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) and, in a lot more detail, in the [Spring IOC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-basic-concepts).

Beans you declare in the `@Configuration` class live as long as their corresponding scope. Your `testBean` bean has singleton scope and therefore lives as long as the containing `ApplicationContext`.